# Is there any ways for show some text when there is no list tile?

Tags: flutter

I want to display 'Empty' text on FirebaseAnimatedList when there is no text tile on it. But I don't know how to.
How to count the number of list tiles?

Comment: User a ternary operator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.